# Slope Of Line Between Two Points With Same X

Tags: math, 2d, point

I am implementing a 2D football game.  For my pass algorithm, I calculate the slope between the passer and reciever with the equation `m = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)`

In some conditions `x2` and `x1` are equal resulting in a divide by zero exception.  What should  I do in this case?

I did not ask this question on [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com) because it's a programming question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use the slope of a line for this sort of operation, for just the reason you have stumbled across.  Use instead the angle of the line from passer to passee.  Apply a little trigonometry.  If that little trigonometry is beyond you, delete this question, do some work, then post again when you get stuck again.

**EDIT**

I suggest you use trigonometry for 2 reasons.

1. Because the slope of a line between two points with the same x coordinate is indeterminate.  Yes, you could, as the other answer suggests, fiddle around and make the slope a very large value when the x coordinates are the same, but it's an unnecessary compromise when trigonometry, which will produce an angle whatever the x and y coordinates, is available.
2. Trigonometry will give you a natural interpretation of the value of the angle from passer to passee.  A pass at an angle of 90 degrees (pi/2 radians, though I'm not sure many footballers or fans think of angles in radians during a match) means a cross-field pass (I'm assuming that your y-axis aligns with the long axis of your pitch), a pass at an angle of 180 degrees is a back pass, and so forth.

Comment: thanks for your answer,why do you suggest using trigonometry instead of slope?yes i know something about that

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to skip the Trig application, you could check `if(x1 != x2) //whatever math needs to be done`

This way, if the x's are equal, you could set your own value for a "flat pass" in the else statement and never have to worry about a divide by zero exception again.

Good luck with whatever route you choose!  (I would recommend using Trig if you have the time to learn it (if necessary))